# How can child reach parent object position and stick on it?

Tags: modeling, animation

I'm going to make an animation of the stone golem creation. Each stone on the ground flies up and reaches parent's position. I mean one stone should be placed on foot, another on arm etc etc. I want to every stone smoothly reach specific place on the armature while golem wakes up.

How can I make this kind of effect?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using **Child of** constraint. It works like parenting, but it has **influence** value. If **influence** sets to 0 object is free, if 1 - object follows to target.

[image]

You can make smooth transition between parenting and free position by animating this value:

[image]